# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working on some devices

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with sending push notifications from server via FCM.

1. So at first everything was working fine after adding push notifications.
2. I had to change the package name of an android app so I added new app on Firebase with new package name and I have downloaded new json file, and changed the name in manifest file and gradle.
3. After doing it, I noticed that on some smartphones these notifications aren't working and on others they work :/

   When I'm using only Firebase to send push notification (the firebase console) - it works. But when I receive the push notification from server on one phone, on another I don't.. I am updating the regId in my database and all notifications on my phone are turned ON. I thought that maybe the problem is that I have 2 apps in one project in firebase, so I made new project and again downloaded json file but it is the same as earlier.

Have anyone had this kind of problem or anyone knows what could solve it and make it work again? :/

Comment: i faced problem with xiaomi devices when the app is not in background or foreground

Comment: I thought about it, because I am testing it on Jiayu, but my friend has Samsung and the same problem :/ 
Maybe I would think about it that it is problem with Google Play Services (cause I also read about it) or the phone, but if it is, why Iit worked earlier? No idea :(

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on device you were trying it on.

if the google play services is out of date you could try updating it from playstore.see if that fixes the problem.

if it has no google api/Playstore (so no amazon products and some none market devices)

push messaging does not work along with authentication. The realtime Data base still works but fires off an error in logcat.

ive been pulling my hair out for weeks trying to figure it out.. thought it was my code.. so i sent the firebase team a email to ask. They confirmed that there was no fix for this at the present time.. hope this helps